# How can I load a Firefox extension cross-platform in a functional test CI environment?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, karma-runner, functional-testing

I'm trying to run functional tests in Firefox of some javascript code that relies on an extension to be loaded. In Chrome, I'm able to do this by telling the browser launcher to launch Chrome with `--load-extension=<path>`. I have not found an analog to this in Firefox, nor any other clear way to do this.

My first attempt was to try to launch Firefox with a custom profile using the `-profile <path>` command line switch, but when trying to reverse-engineer the firefox profile extension metadata it looks like there are some absolute paths in there that would make the profile not portable (i.e. i couldn't check it into git and have another developer be able to clone and run tests, because it would be looking for my machine's paths).

Does anyone know a good way to handle this? I'd really like it if I wasn't forced to generate the extensions.json each time the tests are run.

For what it's worth, I am running my functional tests using karma & karma-firefox-launcher in node.js

Comment: By portable do you mean move the folder around? Can you explain more about that please. Because once a profile folder is made its not intended to be moved, even custom folders. But it should work without breaking, although super recommended against, but this warning was never made clear i think.

Comment: I was originally trying to set it up so that I could point Firefox at a profile that I had checked into git, but I've since found a better way. Posting an answer now...

Answer (score 1):

After doing some [more](https://mike.kaply.com/2012/02/09/integrating-add-ons-into-firefox/) [research](https://mike.kaply.com/2012/02/21/understanding-add-on-scopes/), I found a solution. You can script the creation of an empty directory (say 'tempProfile') and create the following contents:

*tempProfile/prefs.js*

```
user_pref("extensions.autoDisableScopes", 0);
user_pref("extensions.enabledScopes", 15);
```

*tempProfile/extensions/*

place your extension here. The extension's filename must exactly match the 'id' of the extension, with `.xpi` as its file extension. You can discover the 'id' of the extension by extracting the .xpi (i.e. `unzip XXX.xpi`) and opening the install.RDF file with a text editor. Look for the `em:id` tag under the `Description` tag.

For example, if your install.RDF file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>myCustomExt@suchandsuch</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
    <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

    [...]
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

Then you should set the filename of the extension to `myCustomExt@suchandsuch.xpi`.

Once you have the profile setup, you can run Firefox with `Firefox -profile /path/to/tempProfile`

Anyway, `karma` and `karma-firefox-launcher` already do much of the work of automating this for you on each browser run, so I just patched that project to add support for placing the extensions in the right place and setting the necessary prefs. I submitted a PR and it is [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/pull/35).

Comment: Thanks very much for this research and share!